# How to get data from a repository from within a cubit?

Tags: flutter, dependency-injection, repository, bloc

i'm using flutter bloc. i want to emit the data from a repo to a state.

how do i get the data from the repo to show in the cubit?

This is my cubit:

```
 void getProfile(userId) async {
try {
  final data = await profileRepository.fetchProfile(userId: userId)
      as Map<String, dynamic>;
  if (data != null) {
    final _userId = (data['userId'] ?? '') as String;
    final _username = (data['username'] ?? '') as String;
    final _avatarUrl = (data['avatar_url'] ?? '') as String;
    final _website = (data['website'] ?? '') as String;

    print('this is from a cubit');
    print('$_userId $_username $_avatarUrl $_website');
  }
} catch (_) {
  emit(const _Failure());
}
```

}

this is my repo:

```
Future fetchProfile({
    required String userId,
    String? username,
  }) async {
    try {
      final response = await supabase
          .from('profiles')
          .select()
          .eq('id', userId)
          .single()
          .execute();
      final data = response.data as Map<String, dynamic>;
      if (data != null) {
        _userId = (data['userId'] ?? '') as String;
        _username = (data['username'] ?? '') as String;
        _avatarUrl = (data['avatar_url'] ?? '') as String;
        _website = (data['website'] ?? '') as String;
      }
      print('fetched profile profile inside repository');
      print('$_userId $_username $_avatarUrl $_website');

      return;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

the print statement from the repo works fine.
the print statement from the cubit fails.

thanks

Comment: As you have _Failure when there is error, have you declared any for success.

Comment: Yes I would put it in place of the print Statement but that's not working either. I found the problem is my return statement needed to be:  return data

Comment: You are not returning the data from `fetchProfile` function

Answer (score 1):

Duh. All I needed to do was change the return statement in `fetchProfile` to:

```
return data;
```